# What kind of window can be docked in Win7?

Tags: windows-7, avalondock

I have been developing a toy editor, and I want my editor to look like the VS2010 text editor which can be dragged out of the main window to become a independent window and the dragged-out window can be maximized when it's dragged to the top of the screen, and can be docked by being dragged to the left or right side of the screen(which is a new feature in Win7).

So I tried to use AvalonDock(a codeplex project) to do that.But I found the dragged-out DocumentContent(a class in AvalonDock,it inherits from ContentControl) is not treated like a real window in Win7.

So I wanna know that What kind of window can be docked by being dragged to the left/right side or the top of the screen in Win7?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out.
Just right click on the dragged-out DocumentContent and select "Floating".
Then it's all OK.